# chrome расширение, js-инъекция. Как забрать данные в свою базу?

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

background.js

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.src=chrome.extension.getURL("injected.js");
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].appendChild(s);

window.addEventListener("message", function(event) { // получаю отправленные данные из инъекции 
    if (event.source != window)
        return;

    if (event.data.type && (event.data.type == "myData")) {
        console.log("Content script received message: " + event.data);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(event.data));
    }
});
```

injected.js

```
function injected_main() {    
    myHTML = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerHTML;
    ... разбираю нужные мне данные...
    window.postMessage(myData, "*"); // отправляю нужные данные в background.js
}
```

Вышеизложенное работает как надо. А вот далее уже лыжи не ехают...

А теперь вопрос: как эти данные получить мне на моем сервере?

Первое, с чем столкнулся, не формируется ajax запрос в сторону моего веб-сервера на мою php'шку. Не нравится ему, что https на http формирую.

Следующий вопрос: переведя свой домен на https не скажет ли он мне, что отправить на чужой домен не получится? (по своим политикам безопасности)

Вумные люди, подскажите способ!

Comment: А вы permissions в манифесте поправили?

Comment: Попробуйте из background скрипта слать запрос

Comment: МАНИФЕСТ МОЙ  {
      "name": "dn",
      "version": "1.0",
      "manifest_version": 2,

      "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "boy.png",
        "default_title": "dn"
      },

      "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": [ 
     "https://www.notmysite.com/*"
           ],
          "js": [ "background.js" ]
        }
      ],

    "externally_connectable": {
      "matches": ["https://www.notmysite.com/*"]
    },

      "web_accessible_resources": [
     "injected.js"
      ]

    }

Comment: Ведет себя одинаково, что из background, что из самой внедренной js = https на http не нравится ему

Comment: Как именно звучит ошибка о невозможности выполнить запрос?

Comment: Уже перевел свой домен на https и заработало. (поэтому ошибку уже не вижу). Спасибо за отзывчивость!)